# check if day of month is between two months

Tags: python, python-datetime

I want to check if a `(month,day)` is between two months **regardless of the year**. I am having a problem in modeling the month of **january**. I tried representing january by 13 but I got stuck.

---

## return values

- **3** = between 25JUN and 22AUG
- **2** = between 01APR-24JUN or 22AUG-31OCT or 17DEC-01JAN
- **1** = between 01SEP-31MAR or 01NOV-16DEC or 02JAN-31MAR
- **0** = My program is not working and couldn't find the dates. I am screwed

---

## source code

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

def get_season(date):
        month = date.month
        day   = date.day
        
        if month == 1:
            month = 13
        
        if (6,25) <= (month, day) <= (8,22):
            return 3
        
        elif (4, 1) <= (month, day) <= (6,24) or (8, 22) < (month, day) <= (10, 31) or (12,17) <= (month, day) <= (13,1):
            return 2
        
        elif  (9, 1) <= (month, day) <= (3, 31) or  (11,1) <= (month, day) <= (12, 16) or (13,2) <= (month, day) <= (3, 31):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    date = datetime.strptime("2016-02-01",'%Y-%m-%d').date()
    
    if get_season(date) == 0:
      print "WRONG DOES NOT EXIST THERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to compare. You want to return `2` if the given date is between April 1st and June 24th, or August 22nd and Octover 31st, or December 17th and January 1st (including the first of the year?), is that right?

Comment: yes exactly. But I don't know how to use january

Comment: What are your return values? What do they mean? Also your long `if-elif` does not end in `else`

Comment: @AGNGazer it doesn't have to

Comment: @AdamSmith the problem is here **(12,17) <= (month, day) <= (1,1)** if the day is between the 17th of december and the 1st of january it should return 2.

Comment: @AdamSmith I did not see how long his statements are. However, when running his example, I get `get_season(datetime.strptime("2016-02-01",'%Y-%m-%d').date()) == None` returning `True` which shouldn't happen if his `if` was complete.

Comment: @AGNGazer what should it return instead? Without knowing that, it's tough to say that `None` isn't the correct return value :)

Comment: @AGNGazer nevermind the None. In my program i accept the None it's ok

Comment: What do you mean by _"i accept the None it's ok"_? Also, could you explain what these return values mean?

Comment: Note that in your posted code, a `None` value will pass silently since `None != 0`

Comment: I'm not going to check all the date ranges here, but if your ranges should cover any possible date, it seems like `else: raise ValueError("Date not found in range")` would be more appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do all these comparisons directly between `datetime.date` objects, and re-write them as a single year.

```
from datetime import date

def get_season(d):

    d = date(year=1900, month=d.month, day=d.day)

    if date(1900, 6, 25) <= d <= date(1900, 8, 22):
        return 3

    elif date(1900, 4, 1) <= d <= date(1900, 6, 24) or \
         date(1900, 8, 22) <= d <= date(1900, 10, 31) or \
         date(1900, 12, 17) <= d <= date(1900 12, 31) or \
         date(1900, 1, 1) == d:
        return 2

    elif date(1900, 9, 1) <= d <= date(1900, 3, 31) or \
         date(1900, 11, 1) <= d <= date(1900, 12, 16) or \
         date(1900, 1, 2) <= d <= date(1900, 3, 31):
        return 1
```

This also makes it much easier to create boundary pairs.

```
def get_season(d):
    d = date(year=1900, month=d.month, day=d.day)

    boundarydict = {1: [(date(1900, 9, 1), date(1900, 3, 31)),
                        (date(1900, 11, 1), date(1900, 12, 16)),
                        (date(1900, 1, 2), date(1900, 3, 31))],
                    2: [(date(1900, 4, 1), date(1900, 6, 24)),
                        (date(1900, 8, 22), date(1900, 10, 31)),
                        (date(1900, 12, 17), date(1900, 12, 31)),
                        (date(1900, 1, 1), date(1900, 1, 1))], # note this one!
                    3: [(date(1900, 6, 25), date(1900, 8, 22))]}

    for retval, boundaries in boundarydict.values():
        if any(a <= d <= b for a, b in boundaries):
            return retval
```

Comment: sorry for the question if it wasn't clear. Didn't know i had to add all this.

Comment: @HaniGotc you don't, and the only thing I'm doing to "fix" your code is to write the `or date(1900, 1, 1) == d`, but it's certainly much cleaner to use the batteries-included `datetime.date` objects than building tuples of your own